# Saving Cache Files to Disk in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am working on an Application which deals with audio files. For this application, it is best not to stream the files, since you might download the files to your device and then disconnect from the server and listen to them later, perhaps in areas with no cell reception.

I created a caching system that stores the data to a file path and then stores the file location in CoreData with it's associated data.

```
        self.name = name
        var domainMask = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userDomainMask")

        if domainMask == nil {
            domainMask = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(domainMask, forKey: "userDomainMask")
        }

        var cachePath = domainMask!
        cachePath = (cachePath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(DataCache.cacheDirectoryPrefix + name)
        self.cachePath = cachePath
        
        ioQueue = DispatchQueue(label: DataCache.ioQueuePrefix + name)
        
        self.fileManager = FileManager()
    }
```

But when I try it on device, it is able to access the data at the file path, but it fails to load the file and play it.

The kicker is, when I share a file from my phone, it is able to find the file and upload it to the server, then retrieve it from the cache and display and play the file. If I re-run the application, it returns to a state where it can access the data, but the audio file does not load.

Comment: Why are you storing the user domain mask in user defaults.  It isn't a particularly expensive operation just to get it from file manager. It definitely looks like the sort of value that you shouldn't store. You could fetch it once and hold it in memory in a property if you are going to use it a lot, but I definitely wouldn't store it in user defaults.

Comment: Why have you shown this piece of code?  It doesn't seem all that relevant to the problem. You say it "failed to load the file and play it". You should probably show that code and explain *how it fails*. What errors do you get?  Which operation, specifically, fails

Comment: Your question "Why are you storing the user domain mask in user defaults" led me to the answer, which is of course that I was assuming the absolute file url of the cache would be identical every run all of the time, when this is inaccurate. I agree the above code actually wasn't where the problem was, but in a wrong way, it was exactly where the problem was. Thanks man, I was wracking my BRAINS on this for days.